# SQL Server : compare two JSON String to find the difference

Tags: json, sql-server

I've not worked JSON that much but a client has asked for a report to see the difference between two columns in a log table (there is 30 tables all together).

The columns I'm interested are `originalRecord` and `newRecord` in the `log` table.

Each column holds all the JSON objects from a screen, lets say 30 text fields, drop down lists etc. The `originalRecord` holds the record before the change, and `newRecord` after the update.

An example, status change from Open to Closed, `originalRecord` has all 30+ fields and status "Open" and `newRecord` has all 30+ fields and status "Closed"

I'm trying to find a way I can compare **ALL** JSON Objects for a record and the difference between the two columns.

I know JSON_VALUE can compare a JSON Object such as

```
IIF(JSON_VALUE(OriginalRecord, '$.status')<> '', NULL, JSON_VALUE(NewRecord, '$.status'))
```

but I don't want to hardcode every object like above as they do change over time.

Comment: Ugh, what a bad design.  It totally negates the purpose of a relational database.  Is your only option to parse this in T-SQL?  And is there no option to normalize the data so it doesn't get stored that way?  Or is it possible to set up new tables with the parsed data?  So, for example, parse the JSON in C# and store in properly normalized table(s)

Comment: @devlincarnate Sadly the design happened before the thought of reports came along. I did think about an ETL tool to split all up into a table and report off that.